# How do I MergeSort a doubly linked list?

Tags: c#, mergesort, doubly-linked-list

I haven't found an implementation for C#, and the implementations I did find for other languages weren't satisfactory in my view ... needing to know the number of nodes in advance, not optimized for doubly vs. singly linked lists or otherwise inefficient, overly complicated ... I will post my own answer.

Comment: Looking at my question 2 years later, it's still quite readable and clearly explains the issues, contrary to the utterly bogus and unnecessary comment above that is pure projection ("Use proper sentences, explaining what the problem"--um, right.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. In my own code, there are more methods in this class, and an accompanying header class, but I've stripped out everything other than the merge sort. This implementation assumes that the head and tail of a list point to a header node that points back to them, and an empty list is represented by a header node with Next and Prev pointing to itself. (This is a classic technique that simplifies things over using null pointers at the head and tail.)

```
public class Node<T> where T: Node<T>
{
    public T Next, Prev;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sorts the nodes from <paramref name="first"/> to <paramref name="last"/> inclusive, in place.
    /// </summary>
    public static void MergeSort(T first, T last, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        // return if 0 or 1 nodes
        if (ReferenceEquals(first, last))
            return;

        // optimization for two nodes
        if (ReferenceEquals(first.Next, last))
        {
            if (comparer.Compare(first, last) > 0)
                MoveBefore(first, last, last);
            return;
        }

        var mid = Midpoint(first, last);

        // a little messy here ... get the nodes before and after each
        // segment before MergeSort reorders it,
        // then determine the new beginning and end from those

        var p1 = first.Prev;
        var p2 = mid.Next;
        MergeSort(first, mid, comparer);
        p1 = p1.Next;
        mid = p2.Prev;

        var ln = last.Next;
        MergeSort(p2, last, comparer);
        p2 = mid.Next;
        last = ln.Prev;

        // merge p1 and p2
        for (;;)
        {
            for (;; p1 = p1.Next)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(p1, p2))
                    return;
                if (comparer.Compare(p1, p2) > 0)
                    break;
            }
            var start = p2;
            do
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(p2, last))
                {
                    MoveBefore(p1, start, p2);
                    return;
                }
                p2 = p2.Next;
            }
            while (comparer.Compare(p1, p2) > 0);

            MoveBefore(p1, start, p2.Prev);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves the nodes from <paramref name="first"/> and <paramref name="last"/> inclusive
    /// from where they are in the list to before <paramref name="target"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static void MoveBefore(T target, T first, T last)
    {
        first.Prev.Next = last.Next;
        last.Next.Prev = first.Prev;

        (first.Prev = target.Prev).Next = first;
        (last.Next = target).Prev = last;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the node midway between <paramref name="first"/> and <paramref name="last"/>.
    /// If there are an even number of nodes, returns the last node in the first half.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Undefined if <paramref name="first"/> and <paramref name="last"/> aren't in the same list.
    /// </remarks>
    public static T Midpoint(T first, T last)
    {
        for (;; first = first.Next)
            if (ReferenceEquals(first, last) || ReferenceEquals(first, last = last.Prev))
                return first;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, why not implementing it for the built-in `LinkedList<T>`?

Comment: @KevinGosse This is a general solution / algorithm. Someone can implement it for `LinkedList<T>` if they want to (it will be more work because that class uses null as the end pointers), but I have various reasons not to use that class (that being one of them). Note that my `Node<T>` serves as a base class (it probably should be made abstract, since it's not of any use without a payload), whereas `LinkedListNode<T>` is sealed.